# Multiple selects which disable each other's options

Tags: jquery, select

I'm using a great jQuery function which disables selection of equal option values, when there is a multiple selects on page. Problem is I don't know how it is doing.

JSFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/Z2yaG/4/

This is what jQuery function looks:

```
var prev = -1;
$("select").change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() > -1) {
            $("select").not(this).find("option[value=" + $(this).val() + "]").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $("select").not(this).find("option[value=" + previous + "]").removeAttr('disabled');}
    else {
             $("select").not(this).find("option[value=" + previous + "]").removeAttr('disabled');
         }
     }).focus(function () {
previous = $(this).val();
});
```

How this WORKS????

Comment: How this WORKS, I'm using this in my work, and I have to know to explain it...

Comment: The part with .not(this).find, and the use of "previous"...

Comment: `this` is the `current select that triggered the change event` . So basically you are selecting all the selects but excluding the `select that triggered the change`.. At any point of time you need to enable the previously selected option. So that variable holds that value so that it can reused later

Comment: Tnx a lot for help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var previous = -1;
// Setting a previously selected value
$("select").change(function () {
// When any select element is changed
    if ($(this).val() > -1) {
    // When value is > -1
        // Get all selects but not the current one which triggered the change event
        $("select").not(this)
           .find("option[value=" + $(this).val() + "]").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        // set the current option value to disabled

         // Get all selects but not the current one which triggered the change event
        $("select").not(this)
            .find("option[value=" + previous + "]").removeAttr('disabled');
        // Remove the disabled property on previous value
    } else {
        // Get all selects but not the current one which triggered the change event
        $("select").not(this)
            .find("option[value=" + previous + "]").removeAttr('disabled');
        // Remove the disabled property
    }
}).focus(function () {
    previous = $(this).val();
    // store the current value of the select to previous 
});
```

Comment: So if I get this correctly? I understand that previous variable holds selected value so that it can reused later, but is the previous an array, or every select has its previous var? I can't understand how function using on .find("option[value=" + previous + "]").removeAttr('disabled') removes only the previous selected value on that specific select. If the previous is array it would remove disable from all selected values????